# BOOST_FOREACH: What is the error on using this of a STL container?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost

Does anyone know why the following generates an error on VC9?

```
class Elem;
class ElemVec : public vector<Elem>
{
    public:
        void foo();
};

void ElemVec::foo()
{
    BOOST_FOREACH(Elem& elem, *this)
    {
        // Do something with elem
    }
    return;
}
```

The error I get is:

```
error C2355: 'this' : can only be referenced inside non-static member functions
```

The only (hack) solution I have right now which compiles without error is:

```
void ElemVec::foo()
{
    ElemVec* This = this;
    BOOST_FOREACH(Elem& elem, *This)
    {
        // Do something with elem
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which compiler/Boost version are you using? I can compile the following without any problem (VS2005/Boost 1.38):

```
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
using namespace std;
struct xxx : std::vector<int>
{
    void test()
    {
        BOOST_FOREACH(int x, *this)
        {
        }
    }
}; 

int main(void) {
    xxx x;
    x.test();
    return 0;
}
```

Search the Boost [bugbase](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/search?ticket=on) if you want more details.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'm on Boost 1.35, I will upgrade to 1.38 and get back to you.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't inherit from STL containers. These are not polymorphic classes and it's the reason `BOOST_FORACH` can't handle your derived class.

Try to use aggregation instead.

Comment: What is BOOST_FOREACH doing that prevents it from being applied on such a class?

Answer (score 0):

I had never seen that error. I guess it comes from the implementation of BOOST_FOREACH macro.

May i ask why you're creating a class based on vector<...> and not having a vector member variable ?

**EDIT**
Following [this thread](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2006/04/103992.php), i found out that this actually is a visual studio bug. The solution you have found seems to be the simplest.

Comment: In this case, I am extending the vector<Elem> with some extra functionality that I need.

Comment: Generally a bad idea - write free functions instead of using inheritance.

Comment: Inheriting from vector is generally bad because of it's non virtual destructor. As long as you are aware of this, extending should be ok..

Comment: Benoit: I am aware of that Boost mailing list thread. What I'm surprised is that it hasn't been fixed since VC7/8 days!

Comment: @indeera  unfortunately not only have you got to be aware of it, the users of your code have too

Comment: @Neil, I agree with you. Perhaps I didn't convey properly, I meant to say generally to cover wide range of scenarios, where as if the author knows the implications of his decisions, he could use this in a    specific application.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, all compiled succesfully on my msvc (2005) compiller.

Maybe you have some error, but fixed or avoided it when was created your example.

Comment: Thanks, as "dirkgently" pointed out, it turned out to be a Boost issue. The error no longer occurs with the latest Boost v1.38.