# C++ Boost: Any gotchas with BOOST_FOREACH?

Tags: c++, boost, loops

This one is for Boost experts. Are there any gotchas or details that the programmer needs to be aware of before he goes in and replaces all his old C/C++ style loops with the lean-and-mean-looking `BOOST_FOREACH`?

(This question is partly derived from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716810).)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at:

- The [Conditional Love](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/foreach.html) article for an understanding of the rationale
- The [Pitfalls](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/foreach/pitfalls.html) section of documentation
- The [Portability](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/foreach/portability.html) section just in case you are developing cross-platform products
- The bugs page for [BOOST_FOREACH](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/search?q=BOOST_FOREACH&noquickjump=1&ticket=on)

Comment: Is point 1 an issue for BOOST_FOREACH? As I understood it BOOST_FOREACH, evaluated each parameter once and only once. No? "It evaluates its arguments exactly once, leading to no nasty surprises" --docs

Answer (score 9):

BOOST_FOREACH - macro, I don't like macroses and prefer to use STL algorithms + lambda + bind.

Also [C++0x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x) will contain [for-loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Range-based_for-loop) similar on BOOST_FOREACH:

```
int my_array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
for(int &x : my_array)
{
  x *= 2;
}
```

it is one additional reason for don't use partialy dead BOOST_FOREACH.

Comment: Actually, this is the reason I started using BOOST_FOREACH. The syntax is similar enough so that once the C++0x construct is available, you can update your code with a simple regex search-and-replace operation.

Comment: I'm skeptic, very skeptic. tr1 is still not available everywhere and that was a long time ago.  C++09 will be fully usable by 2020 at this rate, if C++ doesn't die from bloat.

Comment: Yes, some peoples don't use/like STL for this time and will not use new C++0x features to 2020. But facts says next: VC and GCC compillers already supports some C++0x features.

Comment: That's the problem it's just "some", and that some is the low hanging fruit :/

Answer (score 8):

As it's just a macro, you can't use commas in typenames, so
`BOOST_FOREACH(pair<int,int> A, mapB){}`
won't work.
For other disadvantages I'd consult the [BOOST_FOREACH() documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/foreach/pitfalls.html).

Comment: I believe that BOOST_FOREACH( (pair<int,int> A), mapB) should work. Did not check though.

Comment: Won't work, and I spent half a day trying to figure it our, until it suddenly strict me it was a macro. Macro's don't understand templates and they think the comma is just another argument to replace

Comment: `auto` is your friend! `BOOST_FOREACH(auto a, mapB) {...}`

Comment: @Gabriel Won't work unless you have a very recent compiler. At work we still have GCC 4.1 on some machines.

Comment: @tstenner Works at least with VS2010.

Comment: @Gabriel That what I meant with 'very recent' ;)

Comment: The simple solution is to use `typedef`, for example `typedef pair<int,int> MyIntPair; BOOST_FOREACH(MyIntPair A, mapB)`.

Comment: The simplest solution is to use a tie, explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8859736/375343

Answer (score 7):

I profiled `BOOST_FOREACH` versus a hand-coded loop.
`BOOST_FOREACH` was about 30% slower in a simple loop that incremented the elements of a vector of size 100,000.
So, if you are coding a small loop, it is not going to be as fast. Once your loop does major processing, Amdahl's Law kicks in and the loss due to `BOOST_FOREACH` is negligible.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the source of the BOOST_FOREACH macro (in foreach.hpp) - it's not what I would call "lean and mean" :-)