# C++ BOOST ForEach vs custom defined Macro

Tags: c++, boost, macros, iterator, boost-iterators

What is the Difference between using BOOST's ForEach and my own custom #define macro to iterate through a container??

mine:

```
#define iterate(i,x)     for(typeof(x.begin()) i=x.begin();i!=x.end();++i)

boost:
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::string hello( "Hello, world!" );

    BOOST_FOREACH( char ch, hello )
    {
        std::cout << ch;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Please explain which method is better and why?

Comment: Boost has likely configured their code to run on compilers that don't have the non-standard `typeof` extension.

Comment: One difference would be `BOOST_FOREACH` works with plain arrays, i.e. `char a[] = {"Hello, world!"};`.

Comment: you shouldn't rely on `typeof`, that's not standard C++. you should use `decltype`

Comment: @MariusBancila If you have a compiler that supports `decltype` then it also, in all likelihood, supports range based `for` loops, in which case both the macros are unnecessary. Edit: But, on second thought, I think VS2010 supports the former, but not the latter :-S

Comment: @Praetorian, totally agree.

Comment: @user2313121, also have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716865/c-boost-any-gotchas-with-boost-foreach

Comment: can you use C++11? If so there is a range based for, that would be much better than either.

Comment: In `BOOST_FOREACH`, `x.end()` evaluate one time. And `BOOST_FOREACH` can apply no container class. And `BOOST_FOREACH` can use rvalue range(container), that range evaluate one time.

Comment: And let's not forget std::for_each. It's template based and doesn't need typeof or decltype. :) In any case, if you have range based for loops, use them. It doesn't get more simple and elegant than that.

Answer (score 2):

First big difference, is when you using rvalues, like this:

```
vector<int> foo();

// foo() is evaluated once
BOOST_FOREACH(int i, foo())
{

}

// this is evaluated twice(once for foo().begin() and another foo().end())
iterate(i, foo())
{

}
```

This is because `BOOST_FOREACH` detects if it is an rvalue and makes a copy(which can be elided by the compiler).

The second difference is `BOOST_FOREACH` uses [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) to retrieve the iterators. This allows it to be extended easily. So it will work on arrays and `std::pair`.

The third difference, is your `iterate` macro automatically deduces the type of the range, which can be very convenient on older compilers that support `typeof` but not `auto`. However, `BOOST_FOREACH` will work on all C++03 compilers.

Comment: You seem to be implying that `BOOST_FOREACH` only works on compilers that support `auto`. That's not true. `BOOST_FOREACH` doesn't use any C++11 features, and in fact works on positively ancient compilers. `BOOST_FOREACH` is 100% compliant C++03, which is another difference between it an the OP's `iterate` macro.

Comment: @EricNiebler Sorry, I didn't mean to imply that it required `auto`, I corrected it to make it more clear.